# How can I flash/copy a file I am working on to a usb drive natively in VIM?

Tags: neovim, file, lazyvim

I am using Lazy NeoVim, and I am also in Computer Science competitively. I am looking at Vim to be a fast alternative to others, such as VS code. However, I am still with the issue of having to flash/copy a file quickly to a usb drive. How would I do this quickly natively inside of neovim?